# Board requirements for a chip PCB antenna?

Tags: pcb-design, pcb-antenna, gnss

*TL;DR*: What are the requirements of chip antennas like [this one](https://www.mouser.com/ds/2/23/Beltii-SR4G013-PS-1.0-1003555.pdf) (without LNA) or [this one](http://www.antenova-m2m.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/M20047-Active-GNSS-antenna-Product-Brief.pdf?hsCtaTracking=ea58690b-079b-42ba-8e8f-00496ef70f18%7Cab691c5b-c2c3-4611-9f1d-742569c51386) (with LNA)? I see PCB size specs in the PDF, but I am not sure I understand how the rest has to look.Does this assume that there is a solid uninterrupted ground plane e.g.?

*Long version:*
To start with, I am a physicist, not an electrical engineer, and I admit that this project is a bit over my head, but that is research ... 
Rough assessment of myself: I know what a trace impedance is and I can use an online calculator to calculate one.

I am trying to built a tracker device with GPS (differential, with postprocessing of RAW output), barometric pressure sensors and an IMU, based on a Teensy 3.6. The hardware and software is running, in principle, but I am struggeling with a good GPS antenna solution. It should be as light as possible and have as little footprint as possible. Optimally, The Teensy would dictate the dimensions and everything else would be on the back of the PCB holding the Teensy (grinded down to castellated holes).

I found this [product](https://www.mouser.com/ds/2/23/Beltii-SR4G013-PS-1.0-1003555.pdf) (without LNA) and [this one](http://www.antenova-m2m.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/M20047-Active-GNSS-antenna-Product-Brief.pdf?hsCtaTracking=ea58690b-079b-42ba-8e8f-00496ef70f18%7Cab691c5b-c2c3-4611-9f1d-742569c51386) (with LNA), which seems to suit my needs just fine, but I do not fully understand the requirements on the PCB apart from it's physical dimensions. The Antenova Quick Guide seems to imply that the former can be used without a keepout area on the back site (in contrast to the Antenova Sinica) but I don't understand if there has to be a solid groundplane all over the board or something like that (and if that could be just one layer of a 4-layer board, and if yes, which one).

Any help?

Comment: Everything I find specifies huge PCBs. How do people put GPS in smartwatches?

Comment: I see this a lot "TL;DR:", what does it mean?    I have not been successful myself putting chip antennas on boards.  I think some fine tuning of ground clearance, path length, impedance matching from the drive/receive chip to the antenna is needed, and I don't have the equipment for it.   Bit of a black art it seems.  Good luck with your project.

Comment: Too long; didn't read. It's the most compact version that I can give for people who do not want to know who I am, what I want to do etc.
I also opted for  u.FL connector. Let's see how the animal people can live with an external antenna.

Answer (score 1):

To me, this picture from page 9 of the datasheet answers it all:

[image]

This shows a ground plane on the outer (upper) layer. The chip antenna is soldered directly on top of this layer. Part of the ground plane is covered with solder mask (see the other picture on page 9, only 4 holes are left for the chip antenna to solder on to). The area marked 1 is where the signal connection is.
2, 3 and 4 are grounded.

The ground plane shields the antenna from "seeing" what's underneath so what is there doesn't matter so much. For best performance you would leave the other side (behind the ground plane) of the PCB free of any components but if you must you can put electronics there as well.

Since for the antenna you need only 1 layer, indeed you could make this on a single layer PCB. I would extend the ground plane down as far as you can allow it to, but more than 2 cm might be overkill and not needed.

The active antenna (Antenova Sinica) has a different antenna design, part of the antenna goes under the module so it cannot sit directly on a ground plane as that ground plane would be too close to the antenna. That's why the keep-out area is needed, the Antenova Sinica's antenna also needs to "see" through the module and through the PCB it is mounted on. It's a different design and so has different requirements.

Comment: I see, that makes a lot of sense. I have alos found https://www.u-blox.com/sites/default/files/CAM-M8-FW3_HardwareIntegrationManual_%28UBX-15030063%29.pdf by now, which explains a lot more, for a different module, of course.

Unfortunately, I have not found an active module with a design that does not require a keepout area under the module. The 10mm to biological tissue specified in hte ublox manual is too much for us ...